# Запись свойств в объект JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер. Такой вопрос.

Есть функция-конструктор объекта User:

```
function User(login, lastVisit, avatar) {
    this.login = login;
    this.lastVisit = lastVisit;
    this.avatar = avatar;
}
```

Так я заполняю объект:

```
var user = new User ("name", "01/02/2014", "name.jpg");
```

Все работает. Но на практике заполнение объекта нужно ведь выполнять из функции, потому что данные для заполнения в какой-то момент будем получать из базы данных. То есть как-то так

```
function fillObject() {
    var user = new User ("name", "01/02/2014", "name.jpg");
}
```

И это уже не работает. Очевидно, из-за области видимости.
Как быть? Ведь объект должен быть глобальным, к нему обращения происходят из разных функций

Comment: []()  

    function fillObject() {
        user = new User ("name", "01/02/2014", "name.jpg");
    }

Comment: Протупил. Когда var - получается локальная переменная. Без var - глобальная. Спасибо большое!

Подскажите пожалуйста. Пишут что глобальные переменные - зло, там несколько причин. 

Это ведь не относится к моему случаю, когда речь о глобальной переменной-объекте?

Comment: @silent-box не обязательно делать переменную глобальной, просто объявите ее выше функции. опять, же не понятно почему-бы не сделать

    function fillObject() {
        return new User ("name", "01/02/2014", "name.jpg");
    }

Comment: глобальной переменной и функции не должно быть вообще, зачем они ? насчет return, вот вы где хотите получить значение этого user , т.е. где вызываете fillObject() ? почему бы не написать

    var user=fillObject(); или user=fillObject();

Comment: Повторюсь, глобально мне эти переменные-объекты нужны, потому что я буду обращаться к ним из разных частей приложения. Соответственно оборачивать все это дело в одну функцию некрасиво.

Спасибо за ответы, однако я запутался. Зачем так сложно, если можно создать функцию-конструктор, заполнить объект, потом читать из него и менять его простым присваиванием?

Comment: просто пример сделал с прототипами, чтобы не скучно было. встречный вопрос. зачем вам вообще конструктор, и отдельно заполняющая функция ? чем {login: "a",lastVisit: "b", avatar: "c"} не устраивает ? А return нужен вот для чего, скажем вам нужно заполнить не глобального юзера, а поучить данные по другому юзеру где-то, что вы будете делать ?

Comment: @silent-box, если без глобальных объектов и функций не обойтись, то ведущие программисты JavaScript советуют использовать один глобальный объект для всего приложения. При этом в него помещаются все нужные переменные и функции:

         var MyAppContainer = {};
         MyAppContainer.Classes = {};
         MyAppContainer.Classes.User = function User(login, lastVisit, avatar) {
             this.login = login;
             this.lastVisit = lastVisit;
             this.avatar = avatar;
         }
         MyAppContainer.user = new MyAppContainer.Classes.User("login","name","avatar");

Comment: Спасибо большое. Скажите пожалуйста, а в чем преимущество данного метода? То есть, с чем мы боремся, помещая все в один контейнер?

Comment: @silent-box с зоопарком глобальных переменных, т.к. если все начнут делать глобальные переменные, то очень вероятно пересечение, а так вы называете контейнер именем своей библиотеки/приложения и за остальные куски кода не беспокоитесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже говорили, var создает локальную переменную. Без этого ключевого слова переменная автоматически создается в глобальной области видимости. Но если говорить о том, как лучше, то приведу пример из книги Джона Резига, автора библиотеки JQuery из Mozilla Corporation.

---

### Создание пакета распространения

Завершающим аспектом разработки современного, профессионального кода JavaScript является создание пакета программного кода с целью его распространения или реального применения. Поскольку разработчики стали применять на своих страницах все больше кода JavaScript, возросла вероятность возникновения конфликтных ситуаций. Если в каждой из двух JavaScript-библиотек есть переменная по имени data, или в обеих из них решено добавить различную обработку одного и того же события, то могут возникнуть фатальные конфликты и трудноопределимые ошибки.

Идеальный вариант создания качественной JavaScript-библиотеки дает разработчикам возможность просто указать на нее, используя &lt;script&gt;-тег, и быть уверенным, что  она заработает, не требуя никаких изменений. Чтобы обеспечить качество и универсальную совместимость своего кода, разработчики используют ряд технологий и решений.

Наиболее распространенной технологией устранения помех и влияния на код со стороны другого кода JavaScript, является использование пространства имен. Элементарным (но не обязательно лучшим или наиболее полезным) примером его применения является общедоступная библиотека пользовательского интерфейса, разработанная компанией Yahoo. Пример добавления обработчика события, используя библиотеку Yahoo UI, обладающую развитым пространством имен

```
// Добавление обработчика события mouseover для элемента, имеющего
// в качестве ID значение 'body'
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener('body','mouseover',function(){

    // и изменение фонового цвета элемента на красный
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

});
```

---

Подробнее об этом можно почитать так же в книгах:

1. Флэнаган Д. - "JavaScript. Подробное руководство.", Глава 10 - модули и пространства имен
2. Джон Резиг - "Pro JavaScript Tehniques", Глава 1 - Современное программирование на JavaScript
3. Стефанов С. - "JavaScript Шаблоны", Глава 5 - Шаблоны создания объектов

Отсюда и получается, если без глобальных объектов и функций не обойтись, лучше всего использовать глобальный объект в качестве пространства имен.

```
 var MyAppContainer = {};
 MyAppContainer.Classes = {};
 MyAppContainer.Classes.User = function User(login, lastVisit, avatar) {
     this.login = login;
     this.lastVisit = lastVisit;
     this.avatar = avatar;
 }
 MyAppContainer.user = new MyAppContainer.Classes.User("login","name","avatar");
```